# ¿Como puedo estilizar una grilla de productos que estan sobre distintas listas con CSS puro?

Tags: css3

Necesito estilizar una grilla de productos para una tienda, la grilla deberia ser responsive, y a medida que la pantalla se achica, la cantidad de productos (de tamaño fijo) debe ir disminuyendo (primero 5 productos, luego 4, luego 3, etc). Lo estoy tratando de hacer con CSS grid, o en su defecto hasta intentandolo con flexbox. Pero mi problema esta en que los productos (cuya maqueta viene de una plataforma que no puedo cambiar, solo estilizar) vienen agrupados en distintas listas html, a lo que tengo que llegar es a una sola grilla con todos los productos (como si todo estuviera en una misma lista) y que se vaya adaptando al ancho de la pantalla. ejemplo de la maqueta generico:

`

```
<ul class="lista1">
   <li>Product 1</li>
   <li>Product 2</li>
   <li>Product 3</li>
   <li>Product 4</li>
   <li>Product 5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="lista2">
   <li>Product 6</li>
   <li>Product 7</li>
   <li>Product 8</li>
   <li>Product 9</li>
   <li>Product 10</li>
</ul>

<ul class="lista3">
   <li>Product 11</li>
   <li>Product 12</li>
   <li>Product 13</li>
   <li>Product 14</li>
   <li>Product 15</li>
</ul>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a intentarlo:

```css
ul li {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="lista1">
   <li>Product 1</li>
   <li>Product 2</li>
   <li>Product 3</li>
   <li>Product 4</li>
   <li>Product 5</li>
</ul>

<ul class="lista2">
   <li>Product 6</li>
   <li>Product 7</li>
   <li>Product 8</li>
   <li>Product 9</li>
   <li>Product 10</li>
</ul>

<ul class="lista3">
   <li>Product 11</li>
   <li>Product 12</li>
   <li>Product 13</li>
   <li>Product 14</li>
   <li>Product 15</li>
</ul>
```

Segun parece, eso hace el truco y tecnicamente es responsivo.  Espero que te pueda ayudar este ejemplo.  Saludos